# Symfony webpack "Highcharts is not defined"

Tags: symfony, webpack, highcharts

Attempts to modify a working Symfony 3 implementation of highcharts in a Symfony 4 version (using Ob\HighchartsBundle) have failed with javascript console reporting

> Highcharts is not defined

Edit: highcharts is installed with `yarn add highcharts`.

Edit 2: If `{{ encore_entry_script_tags('highcharts') }}` is replaced with `<script src="//code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>` the chart is displayed. This suggests there is some Symfony-specific reason for the failure.

template includes:

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('highcharts') }}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        {{ chart(chart) }}
    </script>
{% endblock javascripts %}
```

`yarn encore dev` shows:

```
 I  15 files written to public\build
Entrypoint app [big] = runtime.js app.css app.js
Entrypoint highcharts [big] = runtime.js highcharts.js
Entrypoint _tmp_copy = runtime.js
Done in 11.91s.
```

page source includes:

```
<script src="/build/highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
var linechart = new Highcharts.Chart({   <-this line triggers error
...
```

webpack.conf.js:

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
        .setOutputPath('public/build/')
        .setPublicPath('/build')
        .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
        .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
        .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
        .addEntry('highcharts', './assets/js/highcharts.js')
        .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
         .enableSassLoader()
        .autoProvidejQuery()
        .copyFiles({
            from: './assets/images'
        })
        ;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add in your `assets/js/highcharts.js`

```
const Highcharts = require('highcharts/highcharts');  // or require('highcharts/highstock');
window.Highcharts = Highcharts;
```

Highcharts need JQuery, don't forget enabled it.

```
// webpack.config.js
.autoProvidejQuery()

// assets/js/YOUR_MAIN_FILE.css
const $ = require('jquery');
global.$ = global.jQuery = $;
```

Below my install trace

```
composer require encore
composer require ob/highcharts-bundle
yarn install
yarn add @symfony/webpack-encore --dev
yarn add jquery --dev
yarn add highcharts --dev
yarn encore dev
```

Resources

[jQuery Plugins and Legacy Applications](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/legacy-apps.html#accessing-jquery-from-outside-of-webpack-javascript-files)

[Highcharts #4994](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/4994#issuecomment-340632273)

**Edit :**

Full configuration on fresh symfony install

webpack.config.js

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    /*
     * ENTRY CONFIG
     *
     * Add 1 entry for each "page" of your app
     * (including one that's included on every page - e.g. "app")
     *
     * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. app.js)
     * and one CSS file (e.g. app.css) if you JavaScript imports CSS.
     */
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
    .addEntry('highcharts', './assets/js/highcharts.js')
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())
    .enableSassLoader()
    .autoProvidejQuery()
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

package.json

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^0.22.4",
        "bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
        "highcharts": "^7.0.1",
        "jquery": "^3.3.1",
        "webpack-notifier": "^1.6.0"
    },
    "license": "UNLICENSED",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev-server": "encore dev-server",
        "dev": "encore dev",
        "watch": "encore dev --watch",
        "build": "encore production --progress"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0"
    }
}
```

assets/js/app.js

```
/*
 * Welcome to your app's main JavaScript file!
 *
 * We recommend including the built version of this JavaScript file
 * (and its CSS file) in your base layout (base.html.twig).
 */

require('../css/app.css');

const $ = require('jquery');
global.$ = global.jQuery = $;
```

assets/js/highcharts.js

```
const Highcharts = require('highcharts/highcharts');
window.Highcharts = Highcharts;

// place below your Highcharts customisation
```

templates/base.html.twig

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block stylesheets %}
            {# 'app' must match the first argument to addEntry() in webpack.config.js #}
            {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        {% block javascripts %}
             {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
         {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

templates/highcharts/index.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Highcharts Test{% endblock %}

{% block stylesheets %}
  {{ parent() }}
  {{ encore_entry_link_tags('highcharts') }}
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
  {{ parent() }}
  {{ encore_entry_script_tags('highcharts') }}
  <script type="text/javascript">
    {{ chart(chart) }}
  </script>
 {% endblock %}

{% block body %}
  <div id="linechart" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
{% endblock %}
```

src/Controller/HighchartsController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Ob\HighchartsBundle\Highcharts\Highchart;

class HighchartsController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/highcharts", name="highcharts")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        // Chart
        $series = array(
            array("name" => "Data Serie Name",    "data" => array(1,2,4,5,6,3,8))
        );

        $ob = new Highchart();
        $ob->chart->renderTo('linechart');  // The #id of the div where to render the chart
        $ob->title->text('Chart Title');
        $ob->xAxis->title(array('text'  => "Horizontal axis title"));
        $ob->yAxis->title(array('text'  => "Vertical axis title"));
        $ob->series($series);

        return $this->render('highcharts/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'HighchartsController',
            'chart' => $ob,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding `.addPlugin(...` results in `ReferenceError: webpack is not defined`. I am not prepared to modify a third-party's code.

Comment: I edit the post. Have you try required highcharts in your ''assets/js/highcharts.js'' ?

Comment: It should not be necessary to hack highcharts code. It was not required in the past. Can you provide a reference from Symfony that details why one should hack code?

Comment: Question has been edited to show the effect of using highcharts cdn.

Comment: It's not a hack of Highcharts code. `{{ encore_entry_script_tags('highcharts') }}` call the file you have create in `YOUR_PROJECT/assets/js/highcharts.js`, not highcharts himself. This file has been created by `.addEntry('highcharts', './assets/js/highcharts.js')` in your `webpack.conf.js`. This method create a separated file you can call in specific template. It's your choice. I pointed this file to required the Highcharts librairy and you have to do this to avoid your error message.

Comment: Took what I call a spaghetti route, but we finally got there. Apologies for not quite following, although I still consider modifying a vendor's code a hack. I'm not comfortable with this, but since the app is for a small non-profit we'll go with it. The bounty is yours.

Comment: IT'S NOT A VENDOR FILE. it's your file, you have create it! Take a look to the documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html#page-specific-javascript-or-css-multiple-entries

Comment: I did not write highcharts.js - I copied it from a vendor. This, in my mind, it is the vendor's creation, not mine. Future support of that file cannot be done by me. The best I could do is copy it again. But let's end this difference of opinion.

Comment: i think you misunderstood how webpack works. `yarn add highcharts --dev` install Highchart in `node_modules` folder. To use it you have to import it (with `import` or `require`)  in your script. If you look at the symfony 4 documentation you must see that assets folder is the path where you put your own code. When I look your `webpack.js.conf` I understand you have separate your own js code in 2 files : `.addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')` and `.addEntry('highcharts', './assets/js/highcharts.js')`. When your run `yarn encore dev` If `/assets/js/` is empty, webpack create 2 EMPTY files.

Comment: I edit the my post to add a full exemple. (`yarn encore dev` don't create the empty file. You have to create ti)

Comment: I have refined your solution by creating a shim with the two lines you add to highcharts.js, then added a second entrypoint for the shim before the endpoint for highcharts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186606/discussion-between-equapro-and-geob).